# Check dtype of pandas datetime column when it is a timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a timezone aware column in my dataframe and when I run `dtypes` I get the output `datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]`

I am writing a script to ensure that the column data is definitely of type `datatime64[ns]` before I add it to my database.

However when I go to check the column dtype using the following if statement:

`df['date'].dtypes != 'datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]'`

I get the following error message:
`TypeError: Invalid datetime unit in metadata string "[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]"`

So basically... How do I confirm the `dtype` column in a pandas dataframe is of type `datetime[*]` when the column is a timezone aware?

P.S My timezone is London/UTC. I have not done any extra formatting/parsing on the column other than `parse_dates` in `read_csv()` and:
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%T%z')`

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

df['date'].dtypes is an object. You should be able to str() it and then compare:

```
str(df['date'].dtypes) != 'datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]'
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and I solved this way:

```
isinstance(df['col_name'].dtype, pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype)
```

Comment: This is the way to go I think. I'm working on a custom schema validator that I setup as follows: 
```
    for column in target_columns:
        type_targets = schema_definition[column][0]
        if not df[column].dtype in type_targets:
            # this is an awkward fail-over for checking TZ-aware pandas datetime columns, but it works
            if pd.DatetimeTZDtype in type_targets and isinstance(df[column].dtype, pd.DatetimeTZDtype):
                continue
```